# useState hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const app1 = () => {
     let [count, setCount] = useState(10);
     let initialValue = count;
      const increase = () => {
            setCount(count += 1);
            setCount(count += 1);
          }
      const decrease = () => {
            setCount(count -= 1);
            setCount(count -= 1);
          }
      const resetCounter = () => {
           setCount(initialValue);
           console.log(initialValue);
      }        

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={increase}>+</button> {count} <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
        <div><button onClick={resetCounter}>Reset</button></div>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default app1;
```

The Reset Button is not behaving properly. When I click on the Reset Button the initial value 10 is not printed. Instead it prints the current value. Can someone explain and correct the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    const initialValue = 10;
    const app1 = () => {
         let [count, setCount] = useState(initialValue);
    
          const increase = () => {
                setCount(count += 1);
                setCount(count += 1);
              }
          const decrease = () => {
                setCount(count -= 1);
                setCount(count -= 1);
              }
          const resetCounter = () => {
               setCount(initialValue);
               console.log(initialValue);
          }        
    
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <button onClick={increase}>+</button> {count} <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
            <div><button onClick={resetCounter}>Reset</button></div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    
    export default app1;

The issue happens because react renders when you use setCount and updates the initial value everytime.
```

Comment: Thank you. But in my code using array destructuring I am coping the value of count into a variable intitialValue. So initialValue holds a copied value of count. It's not a reference type value. But it's behaving like a reference type.... when the value of count changes, the value of initialValue also changes. I already have copied the value of count into initialValue which is not a reference type. But why is it behaving like a reference-type? Can you please elaborate it a bit????

Comment: The value of initialValue was changing because of the code  'let initialValue = count; '  which was inside the functional component. the line let initialValue = count; was getting excuted each time react re rendered the component. and hence the count was again getting copied into initialValue. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 3):

the initialValue is always the count, which means that it's not 10 it's the current count.
you should extract the initial value outside to a const, i.e:

```
const INITIAL_VALUE = 10;
const app1 = () => {
     let [count, setCount] = useState(INITIAL_VALUE);

...
      const resetCounter = () => {
           setCount(INITIAL_VALUE);
      } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But in my code using array destructuring I am coping the value of count into a variable intitialValue. So initialValue holds a copied value of count. It's not a reference type value. But it's behaving like a reference type.... when the value of count changes, the value of initialValue also changes. I already have copied the value of count into initialValue which is not a reference type. But why is it behaving like a reference-type?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace each call to `setCount(newValue)` with `setCount((oldvalue)=> newValue)`.
This is because you are relying on the old value in order to calculate the new one.
You can learn more here [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: I tried that ... but the output is same.... the behavior is same